# Is it possible to replace Thymeleaf fragment via JQuery directly?

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I'm trying to figure out how to replace the Thymeleaf fragment with jQuery.

This is what I tried:

```
$("#dataTable").replaceWith("user_panel/fragments/languages_list_fragment.html :: #languages_list_element");
```

It performs a replacement, but the element is replaced with text rather than a fragment.

What I anticipate is simply reloading the data without involving the backend.

As I previously stated, I couldn't find any examples on the internet that directly answered my question, which is why I'm asking here.

Comment: a th:fragment is evaluated on the backend, but you can certainly change its content using jQuery with the append function (e.g. $("#old_content_div").empty(); $("#old_content_div").append(newContentDiv);

Comment: Thank you for responding. I realized that your statement that 'th:fragment' is evaluated on the backend is correct, so I'll have to change the content the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Have a look to [htmx](https://htmx.org/) which is build for doing this kind of thing easily. See my blog posts on it for some more info (https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/tags/htmx/).

Comment: @WimDeblauwe  Thank you, I'll definitely check it out!